# Changes to launcher are instantly changing back (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, themes, desktop-background

I edited ~/.profile by adding the line `umask 775` and also changed a color code in `usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css`

After reboot, the launcher and wallpaper lost all changes I made to them, and went back to the default apps (Firefox, Libre Office, etc). If I unlock something from the launcher, it immediately reappears. Also, if I lock something to the launcher, it immediately disappears. I also cannot change the wallpaper (when I click a new picture in System Settings > Appearance, nothing happens).

Rarely, my changes to the launcher stay. But after reboot, its back to the default apps again.

Any idea how I can get the Launcher to function properly again, and restore the ability to change the wallpaper?